# How to get the memory usage in each line of my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below python code  and I want to get the memory usage in each line,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, cbar_kws={'ticks': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}, vmin=0, vmax=10) 
plt.show()


#Create a DataFrame
d = {'Name':['Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Madonna','Rocky','Sebastian','Jaqluine',
   'Rahul','David','Andrew','Ajay','Teresa'],
   'Score1':[62,47,55,74,31,77,85,63,42,32,71,57],
   'Score2':[89,87,67,55,47,72,76,79,44,92,99,69]}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
col_mean=df.mean()
col_std=df.std()
get_disc=df.describe()
```

I tried below, But I am not getting anything.

```
from memory_profiler import profile
@profile
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, cbar_kws={'ticks': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}, vmin=0, vmax=10) 
plt.show()


#Create a DataFrame
d = {'Name':['Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Madonna','Rocky','Sebastian','Jaqluine',
   'Rahul','David','Andrew','Ajay','Teresa'],
   'Score1':[62,47,55,74,31,77,85,63,42,32,71,57],
   'Score2':[89,87,67,55,47,72,76,79,44,92,99,69]}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
col_mean=df.mean()
col_std=df.std()
get_disc=df.describe()
```

Answer (score 2):

`profile` is a decorator, so you need to wrap your script in a function:

```
from memory_profiler import profile
@profile
def everything():    
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
    uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
    ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, cbar_kws={'ticks': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}, vmin=0, vmax=10) 
    plt.show()


    #Create a DataFrame
    d = {'Name':['Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Madonna','Rocky','Sebastian','Jaqluine',
       'Rahul','David','Andrew','Ajay','Teresa'],
       'Score1':[62,47,55,74,31,77,85,63,42,32,71,57],
       'Score2':[89,87,67,55,47,72,76,79,44,92,99,69]}


    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    col_mean=df.mean()
    col_std=df.std()
    get_disc=df.describe()

everything()
```